# Facebook stopped pulling metadata for certain blog posts despite all posts using the same PHP template

Tags: facebook, drupal, templates, metadata

I'm currently using Drupal 6 with a special content type template for all blog posts. At the moment we're not using OG tags but I have it pull the main metadata with content-type, title, image, and description tags and it was working just fine until today.

Despite at least the last 3 posts still displaying properly in URL Linter, the newest for today won't pull any of the metadata. A few other ones I tested at random from the archive aren't pulling information properly either, but the majority are still working.

What would cause a discrepancy in Facebook's URL Linter between pages using the same template?

Answer (score 0):

What is the url?  Are the tags in the header? Are you able to test switching to their new OG open graph tags?  Facebook has been known to deprecate old functionality with little to no warning - and perhaps the old url's are working still because Facebook has already cached the data. It looks like a lot of [people are having this same issue](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=351744) - and I am assuming Facebook will fix it soon if it isn't already fixed.